# Cannot run Invoice ninja using docker

Tags: docker, invoice-ninja

this is my first post here in SO, i want to use Invoice in my machine using Docker and access it locally

This are the steps i done

- Cloned the repo https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles.git
- Generate the APP_KEY
  Question , when i generate the app key i got this error messages, are they suppossed to appear?

In Connection.php line 678:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ninja and table_name = accoun
ts and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
In Exception.php line 18:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

In PDOConnection.php line 38:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

- Edit the env file with the APP_KEY=base64:...
- Run the chown -R command
- I want to acess Invoice Ninja locally so i changed the APP_URL to http://in5.test:8000
- Changed the IP adress in the config/hosts file

-Finally i run docker-compose up and when i entered in5.test in the browser, i get a page not found but if i enter in5.test.localhost i get this page with errors
https://ibb.co/Zzs5w9b

Question, in the compose file there are some lines with
extra_hosts:
- "in5.localhost:192.168.0.124 " #host and ip
I changed the IP adress to match my local IP but when i do that and go to in5.test.localhost i get a 502 bad gateway nginx

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have the same issue, something in the documentation isn't "right"

Comment: Two years later, I am having this same problem.